# Probability of either A or B event to happen.

Tags: probability

I have homework problem stating the possibility of it raining on Saturday is .# and the probability of it raining on Sunday is .#

How can I determine the probability of it raining on the weekend?

I'm just learning the basics of probability so if you could explain it in the most basic form that would be appreciated.

'#' = any percent, just for the sake of learning

Comment: It would be much better to define the probability of rain on a given day as $p$.  It makes for much easier reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have it rain on the weekend, it has to rain on either Saturday or Sunday, or both.  Naively you would say the probability of rain on either day is the sum of $.\#+.\#$ (these are the glyphs you used), but weekends where it rains both days are counted twice in this sum, so you need to deduct the chance it rains both days once.  Assuming (this is a big assumption, but you are often asked to make it in probability problems) that the chance of rain on each day is independent, the chance of rain on both is $.\#^2$, so the overall chance of rain on the weekend is $2.\#-.\#^2$

Answer (score 1):

Consider instead the probability that it doesn't rain on the weekend. This means it doesn't rain on Saturday and it doesn't rain on Sunday. Assuming these are independent events (which they aren't in reality), to get the probability that they both happen we multiply:

$$P_{Dry \ Weekend} = (1-P_{Rain\ Sat})(1-P_{Rain\ Sun}) = 1 - P_{Rain\ Sat} -P_{Rain\ Sun} +  P_{Rain\ Sat} P_{Rain\ Sun}$$

Then using this we can get the probability of rain on the weekend as follows:

$$P_{Rain\ Weekend} = 1 - P_{Dry \ Weekend} = P_{Rain\ Sat} + P_{Rain\ Sun} -  P_{Rain\ Sat} P_{Rain\ Sun}$$

which is exactly the same as what you get using the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

Answer (score 1):

Well, we will have to assume the event of raining on Sunday is independent of that of raining on Saturday (if only because you don't have enough to work with otherwise).

Given $\mathsf P(A), \mathsf P(B)$ and assuming independence then recall:

- The product rule for the intersection of independent events.

  - $\mathsf P(A\cap B) = \color{ghostwhite}{\mathsf P(A)\mathsf P(B)}$
- The additive rule for the union of nonexclusive events.

  - $\mathsf P(A\cup B) = \color{ghostwhite}{\mathsf P(A)+\mathsf P(B)-\mathsf P(A\cap B)}$

Then ask (yourself) if you want the probability for raining on *at least one day*, $\mathsf P(A\cup B)$, or for on *both days*, $\mathsf P(A\cap B)$?